# Visualizing Riemann sum for f(x,y): darker colors, axes in front

Tags: plotting

I'd like to create a picture for a Riemann sum for my Calculus class. I modified this example:
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/Visualize3DRiemannSums.html#

and got this:

```
f = 20/(x^2 + y^2);
Grid[
 Partition[
  Table[
   Show[
    Quiet@DiscretePlot3D[f, {x, 1 + d/2, 2, d}, {y, 1 + d/2, 2, d},
      ExtentSize -> Full,
      FillingStyle -> Opacity[.6],
      PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.19, 1., 0.16]
      ],
    PlotRange -> {{0, 2.3}, {0, 2.3}, {0, 10}},
    ViewPoint -> {2, .5, 1.2},
    Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False},
    Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> None, 
    AxesStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.001], Orange],
    Lighting -> "Neutral",
    PlotRangePadding -> 0,
    ImageSize -> 500,
    Boxed -> False,
    AxesEdge -> {{1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}}],
   {d, {1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16}}],
  2]
 ]
```

Unfortunately, the color for the plot is too dark, by some reason I can't make it lighter. Also, I do not like the axes in front of the picture. How can I fix that? 
[image]

I am open to all suggestions on this topic: choice of a function, choice of a region, colors, etc. I guess, ultimately, I'd like to create the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be a starting point:

```
f = 20/(x^2 + y^2);
GraphicsGrid[
Partition[
Show[{DiscretePlot3D[f, {x, 1 + #/2, 2, #}, {y, 1 + #/2, 2, #}, 
   ExtentSize -> Full, PlotStyle -> Cyan, 
   FillingStyle -> Opacity[1], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 2.5}, {-1, 2.5}, {0, 12}}, Axes -> False, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Ticks -> None, Boxed -> False, 
   ViewPoint -> {1.3, .7, .5}], 
  Graphics3D[{{Text[
      Style["x", 24, Italic, 
       FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], {2.4, 0, 0}]}, {Text[
      Style["y", 24, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], {0,
        2.4, 0}]}, {Text[
      Style["z", 24, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], {0,
        0, 12}]},
    {Text[
      Style["O", 24, Italic, 
       FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], {0, -.5, 0}]},
    {Arrowheads[.02], Thickness[0.007], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2.3, 0}}]}, {Arrowheads[.15], 
     Thickness[0.007], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}}]}, {Arrowheads[.02], 
     Thickness[0.007], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {2.3, 0, 0}}]}}]}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4}] & /@ {1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16}, 2], 
 ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

You can modify the code according to your needs. Enjoy.

Comment: This looks great, thank you!